# Private files works on one site but not another

Tags: 8, files

I have two sites on the same machine - **demo** and **dev**.

They are served from their respective home directories.

I've set up private files on both. All the settings seem to be exactly the same. However, on **dev**, private files work perfectly, but on **demo**, they don't. When you upload a file it gives no indication of error in the GUI, but when you try to access it you get a 404. The dblog says "The file permissions could not be set on private://2018-04/foo.txt." Searching for it on the command line shows that it has been saved to `<webroot>/private:/2018-04/foo.txt` instead of to `/home/demo/private-files/2018-04/foo.txt`.

Although, strangely, it does in fact create the subdirectory `/home/demo/private-files/2018-04/` ! It just does not put the file in there.

On both sites the private file paths are set :

[image: demo show settings]
[image: dev show settings]

And the permissions are exactly the same:

[image: file perms]

There is no difference between the .htaccess in either directory:

[image: empty diff]

What am I missing?

Comment: Do both websites' apache configurations set to use the same user and group. i.e. `www-data:www-data` or separate users like `dev:www-data` or `dev:dev`, etc. I presume the web server is apache, since you mentioned the .htaccess file.

Comment: Yes. I had originally tried to run them as different users, using mpm-itk, but it never worked. I have now removed all references to different users and restarted apache, but it didn't help. Thanks though

Comment: Check the temp folder permissions and see whether you have hardcoded tmp folder path in `settings.php`

Comment: @Razeem, temp file is the default, /tmp for both which has 777 permissions. What is the relevance of this to private files anyway?